# Tensors Vs Matrices (And related questions)

Tags: matrices, tensors, general-relativity

First, I basically just want to know what *exactly* what is the difference between tensors and matrices?

Second, looking for clarification on the following two (possibly confused) thoughts) of my own on this, which follow here.

(1)  I was basically taught in school that a tensor is any object that transforms as:

$T_{\alpha \beta }^{'}\rightarrow  \frac{\partial x _{\alpha }^{'}}{\partial x _{\alpha }} \frac{\partial x _{}\beta ^{'}}{\partial x _{}\beta } T_{\alpha \beta }$

However, is it correct that not all matrices follow this transformation law?  Meaning all tensors can be *represented* as matrices, but not all matrices are necessarily tensors?  (Hence, *THIS* is the difference between matrices and tensors?)

However, if that is true, then it seems a little loose to say matrices are tensors of rank 2, if indeed all matrices do not actually transform as tensors, and therefore are *not* tensors?

(2)  Is it correct that one of things the law of general covariance says is that if a tensor equation is true in one frame then it is true in all frames?  Secondly, is this made possible by the tensor transformation law?

Comment: The answer here is probably helpful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553762/tensors-matrices-covariance-contravariance?rq=1

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412423/differences-between-a-matrix-and-a-tensor, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316723/tensors-in-the-context-of-engineering-mechanics-can-they-be-explained-in-an-int, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

A linear map is the primary object of study in linear algebra. A matrix is a way of representing this map. A tensor is a generalization of a linear map, from which you may extract different representations corresponding to different coordinate choices, in exactly the same way as a choice of basis gives a different representation of a linear map.

Long answer can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2nv4xr/what_exactly_is_a_tensor/cmhcc7z/).